# Missing entry in $3 \times 3$ matrix

Tags: matrices, pattern-recognition

I found a $3 \times 3$ magic square and cannot figure out the missing digit. It is multiple choice (and just a game) but I want to know the pattern.

\begin{align*}
65 && 69 && 13\\
14 && 63 && 22\\
18 && ? && 17
\end{align*}

The possible answers are $78$, $85$, $98$, $51$. Thank you!

Comment: That is not a magic square. The definition of a magic square says that every row and column and the two main diagonals add up to the same number, which your square does not satisfy. Are there any rules given for the square?

Comment: In what sense is that a "magic square"?

Comment: Why would you think that there is a pattern?  You said that the numbers are put in a box.  There's no law that says we can't put in any number we want is there?

Answer (score 1):

Interchange the digits in the entries of the first column. If you choose $98$ the columns of the resulting matrix are  in a simple relation.